# SignalR client disconnected on Azure slots swap

Tags: signalr, azure-web-app-service, signalr.client

I have web app on Azure with 2 slots.

Whenever the slot swap happens, all SignalR clients are disconnected and not even notified about the connection loss.

SignalR events such a Close, Error, Reconnected are never fired on the client.

How to prevent this or at least know when disconnect happens? (of course I need to avoid polling)

Answer (score 1):

> How to prevent this or at least know when disconnect happens?

We could enable SignalR tracing to view diagnositc infomration about events in your SignalR application. How to enable and configure tracing for SignalR servers and clients, we could refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/enabling-signalr-tracing).

**Detecting the reason for a disconnection**

> SignalR 2.1 adds an overload to the server OnDisconnect event that indicates if the client deliberately disconnected rather than timing out. The StopCalled parameter is true if the client explicitly closed the connection. In JavaScript, if a server error led the client to disconnect, the error information will be passed to the client as $.connection.hub.lastError.

**C# server code: stopCalled parameter**

```
public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
{
    if (stopCalled)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Client {0} explicitly closed the connection.", Context.ConnectionId));
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Client {0} timed out .", Context.ConnectionId));
    }

    return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
}
```

**JavaScript client code: accessing lastError in the disconnect event.**

```
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
    if ($.connection.hub.lastError) 
        { alert("Disconnected. Reason: " +  $.connection.hub.lastError.message); }
});
```

More details we could refer to [Detecting the reason for a disconnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#detecting-the-reason-for-a-disconnection).

> How to prevent this?

We could continuously reconnect it.

> In some applications you might want to automatically re-establish a connection after it has been lost and the attempt to reconnect has timed out. To do that, you can call the Start method from your Closed event handler (disconnected event handler on JavaScript clients). You might want to wait a period of time before calling Start in order to avoid doing this too frequently when the server or the physical connection are unavailable. The following code sample is for a JavaScript client using the generated proxy.

```
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
       $.connection.hub.start();
   }, 5000); // Restart connection after 5 seconds.
});
```

More details we could refer to [How to continuously reconnect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#how-to-continuously-reconnect)